# Fast 3 to 7 D interpolation on non uniform & non rectangular grid

Tags: python, performance, interpolation

[COMPLETELY REWRITTEN]

I'm looking for a way of interpolating large set of data in dimensions ranging from 3 to 7.
The data is, by nature, on a non rectangular grid and non uniformly spaced.

I looked every option I could think of (griddata, KDTree + magic, linear interpolation, reworked map_coordinates...): the fastest and most usable tool seems to be Scipy's LinearNDInterpolator function. Linear interpolation in such high dimensions space is fine and should be precise enough.

However, there is one big shortcoming with this class: data with gaps or "concave regions" will produce extrapolated results when I want only interpolation.

This is best seen with some pictures (2-D test). In the following I produce some randomly generated data for X, and VALUE, while Y is upper-bounded by a function of X (just so I create gaps).

[image: Generated data, with gaps]

After rescaling data (mostly done using pieces of code of the LinearNDIterpolator from the master, ie. development, branch), Delaunay triangulation will produce a Convex Hull that includes the gap, and will "extrapolate" in this region. The term "extrapolate" is not really correct here, in a technical sense, but I think would be appropriate given the fact original data is assumed to be sufficiently well sampled so that the big gaps means "no data allowed" (not physical).

To start handling the problem, I "tagged" every Delaunay (hyper-)triangles whose (hyper-)volume is higher than a user-defined threshold (by default the volume equivalent to 5% of the data extent in each dimension).

Generating random data, and evaluating the values using this technique would produce the following figure:

[image: Interpolation of random data]

Black dots (with red or white rings) is the randomly generated data to be evaluated. Red rings indicates points that are being rejected (ie. value = NaN) by my custom class based on LinearNDInterpolator, and white rings show accepted points.
For clarity I've plotted triangles that have been rejected from the original Delaunay triangulation.

As you can see, there are still some white rings points that fall in the gap, which I do not want. This is because the simplex to which they belong has a volume less than the authorized maximum volume (some of these triangles even appear as lines on the figure, so it is hard to see)

My question is: how could I improve from here? What could be done?

I was thinking of grabbing all points that fall in a small ball around each evaluated point, and see if there are points in that. But this is not a good solution since it would be resource-consuming and not precise enough (eg. what about points very close to the bottom of the gap, but yet outside the upper envelope?)

Here is my custom interpolation module I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Custom N-D linear interpolation class, based on scipy's LinearNDInterpolator.

The main differences are:
    - auto-scaling
    - interpolation: inside convex hull (normal behavior), and "close enough" to original data.
      This rejects points that would normally be interpolated by LinearNDInterpolator.
"""

# ================
#  Python modules
# ================
import cPickle
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
from scipy.misc import factorial



# =======================
#  Convenience functions
# =======================
def _inv_log10(x):
    return 10**x


def det(coords):   #, n):
    """
    Return the determinant of the given coordinates (not the usual determinant, but the one used to compute
        the hyper-volume of an hyper-triangle)
    From a Delaunay triangulation, the coordinates of one simplex (ie. hyper-triangle) is given by:
        coords_i = tri.points[simplex_i]
    where
        tri = Delaunay(points)
        simplex_i = tri.simplices[i]

    In an N-dimensional space, the simplex will have N+1 points, each one of them of dimension N.
    Eg. in 3D, a points i has coordinates pi = (xi, yi, zi). Therefore p1 = points 1 = (x1, y1, z1)
              |x1  x2  x3  x4|
              |y1  y2  y3  y4|   |(x1-x4)  (x2-x4)  (x3-x4)|
        det = |z1  z2  z3  z4| = |(y1-y4)  (y2-y4)  (y3-y4)|
              |1   1   1   1 |   |(z1-z4)  (z2-z4)  (z3-z4)|
    """
    # assert n == len(coords[0]), 'number of dimensions of coordinates (%d) != %d' % (len(coords[0]), n)
    q = coords[:-1, :] - coords[-1, None, :]
    sign, logdet = np.linalg.slogdet(q)

    return sign * np.exp(logdet)


# ==============================
#  LinearNDInterpolator wrapper
# ==============================
class Interp(object):
    """
    Simple wrapper around LinearNDInterpolator.
    """
    def __init__(self, points, values, **kwargs):
        """
        :param points: list of coordinates (eg. [(0, 1), (0, 3), (4, 4.5)] for 3 points in 2-D)
        :param values: list of associated value(s) for each point (eg. [1, 2, 3] for 3 points of single value)

        :keyword rescale: rescale data points so that the final extents is [0, 1] in every dimensions
        :keyword transform: transform data points (prior to rescaling). If True, automatically transform dimension coordinates
                          if extents span more than 2 order of magnitudes. It can also be a list of tuples of
                          (transformation function, inverse function), that will be applied whenever needed.
        :keyword fill_value: outside bounds interpolation values (default: np.nan)
        """
        try:
            points = np.asanyarray(points, dtype=np.float64)
            values = np.asanyarray(values, dtype=np.float64)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Cannot convert input points to an array of floats')

        # dimensions / number of points and values
        self.ndim = points.shape[1]
        self.nvalues = values.shape[1]
        self.npoints = points.shape[0]

        # locals
        self._idims = range(self.ndim)

        # extents
        self.minis = np.min(points, axis=0)
        self.maxis = np.max(points, axis=0)
        self.ranges = self.maxis - self.minis
        self.magnitudes = self.maxis / self.minis

        # options
        rescale = kwargs.pop('rescale', True)
        transform = kwargs.pop('transform', True)
        fill_value = kwargs.pop('fill_value', np.nan)

        # transformation
        if transform:
            transforms = []
            if transform is True:
                # automatic transformation -> if extent >= 2 order of magnitudes: f(x) = log10(x)
                for i, e in enumerate(self.magnitudes):
                    if e >= 100.:
                        transforms.append((np.log10, _inv_log10))
                    else:
                        transforms.append(None)
                if not transforms:
                    transforms = None
            else:
                err_msg = 'transform: both the transformation function and its inverse must be given in a tuple'
                if not isinstance(transform, (tuple, list)):
                    raise ValueError(err_msg)
                if (self.ndim > 1) and (len(transform) != self.ndim):
                    raise ValueError('transform: None or transformations tuple must be given for every dimension')
                for t in transform:
                    if not isinstance(t, (tuple, list)):
                        raise ValueError(err_msg)
                    elif t is None:
                        transforms.append(None)
                    else:
                        transforms.append(t)
            self.transforms = transforms
        else:
            self.transforms = None
        points = self._transform(points)

        # scaling
        self.offset = 0.
        self.scale = 1.
        self.rescale = rescale
        if rescale:
            self.offset = np.mean(points, axis=0)
            self.scale = (points - self.offset).ptp(axis=0)
            self.scale[~(self.scale > 0)] = 1.0                 # avoid division by 0
        points = self._rescale(points)

        # triangulation
        self.tri = self._triangulate(points)

        # volumes
        self.fact = 1. / factorial(self.ndim)
        self.volume_max = np.product(self.tri.points.ptp(axis=0) * 0.05)        # 5% peak-to-peak in each dimension
        self.rej_idx = None
        self.rej_vol = None
        self.cached_rej = False

        # linear interpolation
        self.fill_value = fill_value
        self.func = LinearNDInterpolator(self.tri, values, fill_value=fill_value)

    def _triangulate(self, points, **kwargs):
        """
        Delaunay triangulation
        """
        return Delaunay(points, **kwargs)

    def _get_volume_simplex(self, point):
        """
        Compute the simplex volume of the given point
        """
        i = self.tri.find_simplex(point)
        idx = self.tri.simplices[i]
        return np.abs(self.fact * det(self.tri.points[idx]))

    def cache_rejected_triangles(self, p=None, check_min=False):
        """
        Cache the indexes of rejected triangles.

        OPTIONS
            p               -- peak-to-peak percentage in each dimension for the maximum volume calculation
                                Default: None (default at __init__: p = 0.05)
                                Type: float (0 < p <= 1)
                                Type: list of floats (length = # dimensions) 

            check_min       -- check that the minimum spacing in each dimension is at least equal to p * extent
                                Default: False
                                Warning: *p* must be given
        """
        self.cached_rej = True
        if p is not None:
            p = np.array(p)
            # update the maximum hyper-triangle volume (p % of the extent in each dimension)
            self.volume_max = np.product(self.tri.points.ptp(axis=0) * p)
        if check_min:
            assert p is not None, 'You must give *p* parameter for checking minimum volume of hyper-triangle'
            ptps = self.tri.points.ptp(axis=0)
            ps = np.ones(self.ndim) * p
            n_up = 0
            for i in self._idims:
                _x = np.unique(self.tri.points[:, i])
                mini = np.min(_x[1:] - _x[:-1])
                if mini > (ptps[i] * ps[i]):
                    n_up += 1
                    print 'WARNING: changed max. volume axis of dim. %d from %.3g to %.3g' % (i+1, ps[i], mini)
                    ps[i] = mini
            if n_up:
                new_vol = np.product(ptps * ps)
                print 'CHANGE: old volume was = %.3g, and is now = %.3g' % (self.volume_max, new_vol)
                self.volume_max = new_vol

        rej_idx = []
        rej_vol = []
        for i, simplex in enumerate(self.tri.simplices):
            vol = np.abs(self.fact * det(self.tri.points[simplex]))
            if vol > self.volume_max:
                rej_idx.append(i)
                rej_vol.append(vol)
        self.rej_idx = np.array(rej_idx)
        self.rej_vol = np.array(rej_vol)

    def _transform(self, points, inverse=False):
        """
        Transform point coordinates using functions. Set 'inverse' to True to transform back.
        """
        if self.transforms is not None:
            j = 1 - int(inverse)
            for i in self._idims:
                t = self.transforms[i]
                if t is None:
                    continue
                points[:, i] = t[j](points[:, i])

        return points

    def _rescale(self, points, inverse=False):
        """
        Rescale point coordinates so that extents in each dimensions span [0, 1]. Set 'inverse' to True to scale back.
        """
        if self.rescale:
            if inverse:
                points = points * self.scale + self.offset
            else:
                points = (points - self.offset) / self.scale

        return points

    def _check(self, x, res):
        """
        Check that interpolation results are close enough to real data and have not been extrapolated.
        """
        points = np.asanyarray(x)
        if points.ndim == 1:
            # only 1 point
            values = np.asanyarray(res).reshape(1, self.ndim)
        else:
            # more than 1 point
            values = np.asanyarray(res).reshape(points.shape[0], self.ndim)

        if self.cached_rej:
            idx = np.unique(np.where(np.isfinite(values))[0])
            ui_tri, uii = np.unique(self.tri.find_simplex(points[idx]), return_inverse=True)
            umask = np.lib.arraysetops.in1d(ui_tri, self.rej_idx, assume_unique=True)
            mask = umask[uii]
            values[idx[mask], :] = self.fill_value
        else:
            for i, v in enumerate(values):
                if not np.isnan(v[0]):
                    vol = self._get_volume_simplex(points[i])
                    if vol > self.volume_max:
                        # reject
                        values[i][:] = self.fill_value
        return values.reshape(res.shape)

    def __call__(self, x, check=False):
        """
        Interpolate. If 'check' is True, check that interpolated points are close enough to  real data.
        """
        _x = self._rescale(self._transform(x))
        res = self.func(_x)
        if check:
            res = self._check(_x, res)
        return res

    def ev(self, x, check=False):
        """
        Alias for __call__
        """
        return self.__call__(x, check=check)

    def get_original_points(self):
        """
        Return original points
        """
        return self._transform(self._rescale(self.func.points, inverse=True), inverse=True)

    def get_original_values(self):
        """
        Return original values
        """
        return self.func.values


# ===========================
#  Save / load interpolation
# ===========================
def save(filename, interp):
    """
    Dump the Interp instance to a binary file with cPickle (protocol 2)
    """
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        cPickle.dump(interp, f, protocol=2)


def load(filename):
    """
    Load a previously saved (cPickled with save_interp function) Interp instance
    """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        interp = cPickle.load(f)
    return interp
```

And the test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


"""
Test the custom interpolation class (see interp.py)
"""

import sys
import numpy as np
from interp import Interp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# generate random data
n = 2000        # number of generated points
x = np.random.random(n)
def f(v):
    maxi = v ** (1/(v+1e-5)) * (v - 5.) ** 2 - np.exp(v-7) + 1
    return np.random.random() * maxi
y = map(f, x * 10)
z = np.random.random(n)
points = np.array((x, y)).T
values = np.random.random(points.shape)

# create interpolation function
func = Interp(points, values, transform=False)
func.cache_rejected_triangles(p=0.05, check_min=True)

# generate random data + evaluate
pts = np.random.random((500, points.shape[1]))
pts *= points.ptp(0)
pts += points.min(0)
res = func(pts, check=True)

# rejected points indexes
idx_rej = np.unique(np.where(np.isnan(res))[0]) 
n_rej = len(idx_rej)   
print '%d points (%.0f%%) have been rejected' % (n_rej, 100.*n_rej/pts.shape[0])

# plot rejected triangles
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
for i in func.rej_idx:
    _x = [p for p in points[func.tri.simplices[i], 0]]
    _x += [points[func.tri.simplices[i][0], 0]]
    _y = [p for p in points[func.tri.simplices[i], 1]]
    _y += [points[func.tri.simplices[i][0], 1]]
    ax.plot(_x, _y, c='k', ls='-', zorder=100)

# plot original data
ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], c='b', linewidths=0, s=20, zorder=50)

# plot all points (both accepted and rejected): in white
ax.scatter(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], c='k', edgecolors='w', linewidths=1, zorder=150, s=30)

# re-plot rejected points: in red
ax.scatter(pts[idx_rej, 0], pts[idx_rej, 1], c='k', edgecolors='r', linewidths=1, zorder=200, s=30)
fig.savefig('img_tri.png', transparent=True, dpi=300)
```